# Breaking Out of Recursion AND Returning a Boolean Value in Java

Tags: java, recursion

I have an array and I have to write a method with boolean return type to check the elements of array to see if they are in ascending order using recursion. What I want to do is to break out of  recursion AND at the same time return false as soon as I find the first violation. Is that possible and if yes how?

The exercise tells that I have to use recursion not for or while loop. This is what I have written so far.

```
public class ProveIfSorted
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        int[] myArray = new int[] {1, 3, 5, 7, 9};

        System.out.println("The array is sorted: " + checkSorted(myArray, 4);
    }

    private static boolean checkSorted(int[] array, int i)
    {
        if(i == 0)
        {
            boolean isSorted = true;
            return isSorted;
        }
        else
        {
            if(array[i] >= array[i - 1] == isSorted(int[] array, (i - 1))
            {
                return isSorted = true;
            }
            else
            {
                ?????;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just return false instead of calling the function recursively, if you find a violation.

Comment: One possible approach: Write a function that accepts an array and an integer index (for instance, `boolean isAscending(int[] array, int index)`). Then if you reach the end of your array, return true (you found no violations). If you find a violation, return false. If you haven't found a violation but are not at the end of your list, return `isAscending(array, index + 1)`

This approach is almost certainly covered in your textbook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private boolean isSorted(int[] arr, int start) {
  if (arr.length - start < 2) 
      return True;

  if (arr[start] > arr[start+1])
      return False;

  return isSorted(arr, start+1)

}
```

Comment: The code is good, but the answer would benefit from at least a little explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Seems relatively straightforward.  I'll describe pseudocode, since the actual code is simple enough.

(Prerequisite:  your function should accept the array and two ints (first, second) as arguments.  Another variation is to have one int parameter, and use it in two contexts.)

- Boundary check on the array - if it's zero or null, return `false`.
- Boundary check on the two int arguments:  if the second argument is larger than the length of the array, return `true`. We've since stepped off of the array, and found no violations.
- Actual check conditions:

  - If the value in the array[first] is less than (or equal to) the value in array[second], then we can safely continue recursion; return the call of the method and increment first and second by 1.
  - Otherwise, return `false`.

Answer (score 0):

This code will recursively check if the element is less than the element above it. The recursive part is that it will return the call to itself. If the element is less than the next, it continues. If it hits the end, it returns true. If at any time the element is greater than the next, it will return false, stopping the recursion.

```
public static void main(String args[]){
        int[] myArray = new int[] {1, 3, 5, 3, 6};
        int[] myArray1 = new int[] {1, 3, 5, 6, 6};

        System.out.println("The array is sorted: " + checkSorted(myArray, 0));// Outputs false
        System.out.println("The array is sorted: " + checkSorted(myArray1, 0));//Outputs true
    }

    private static boolean checkSorted(int[] array, int i){
        if(i+1 < array.length){
            if(array[i] <= array[i+1]){
                return checkSorted(array, i+1);
            }else{
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example using tail recursion. Comments should explain. It's deceptively simple.

```
public class ProveIfSorted{

    public static void main( String[] args ){
        int[] myArray = new int[]{ 1, 3, 5, 5, 10, 17, 19 };
        System.out.println( "The array is sorted: " + checkSorted( myArray ) );
    }

    /**
     * This is the public entry point which should be kept as simple as possible.
     * All the caller has is the array, so that is all that should be asked.
     * The public interface should not pass the burden of setup to the caller.
     * Think of this as the wrapper or setup method for the recursive method.
     * 
     * @param array the array under test. Null or empty arrays are considered to
     *               be unsorted -- by definition.
     * @return {@code true} if the array is sorted ascending.
     */
    public static boolean checkSorted( int[] array ){
        // Now we call the recursive method -- if the array is not null. Here we
        // pass in index values and an indicator for what we have found so far.
        // At this point, all we're conserned about is if the array is null or
        // empty.
        return checkSorted( array, 1, array != null && array.length > 0 );
    }

    /**
     * This is the private work horse. Using tail recursion, we can exit if the
     * result of the previous invocation found the array to be unsorted or if we
     * have arrived at the end of the array. Otherwise, we call ourselves with
     * the next index value and the result of the comparison of this entry with
     * the previous entry.
     *
     * @param array the array under test
     * @param ndx    the array slot to examine with the previous slot
     * @param sorted the result of the last examination. As long as this is
     *                {@code true}, we continue testing.
     * @return {@code true} if the array is sorted ascending.
     */
    private static boolean checkSorted( int[] array, int ndx, boolean sorted ){
        if( !sorted || ndx == array.length ){
            return sorted;
        }
        else{
            return checkSorted( array, ndx + 1, array[ ndx - 1] <= array[ ndx] );
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

If the function does just that then simply write return false within the loop when you find your match and at the end outside your loop write  return true.  If function has additional activities to perform aftr this check, then create a boolean variable with default value true before your loop, set the boolean variable to false within loop when it matches and add a break statement. 
E.g.

```
boolean Nomatch = true;
for(int i=0;i<10;i++) {
 if(i==5) {
     Nomatch = false;
     break;
 }
 }
```

Comment: That's not recursive, though.  That's kind of the whole point of this exercise.